# SSE: reinterpret_cast<__m128*> instead of _mm_load_ps

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd

I am in the process of coding up a simple convolution function in C++, starting from the very basic "sliding-window" convolution with regular products (no FFT stuff for now), up to SEE, AVX and possibly OpenCL. I ran into a problem with SSE though. My code looks like this:

```
for (x = 0; x < SIZEX - KSIZEX + 1; ++x)
{
    for (y = 0; y < SIZEY - KSIZEY + 1; ++y)
    {           
        tmp = 0.0f;

        float fDPtmp = 0.0f;
        float *Kp = &K[0];


        for (xi = 0; xi < KSIZEX; ++xi, Kp=Kp+4)
        {                               
            float *Cp = &C[(x+xi)*SIZEY + y];

            __m128 *KpSSE = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(&K);
            __m128 *CpSSE = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(&C[(x + xi)*SIZEY + y]);
            __m128 DPtmp = _mm_dp_ps(*KpSSE, *CpSSE, 0xFF);
            _mm_store_ss(&fDPtmp, DPtmp);

            tmp += fDPtmp;
        }

        R[k] = tmp;
        ++k;
    }
}
```

The necessary matrices are initialized like this (the size of those is considerd ok because the simpler implementations work just fine):

```
__declspec(align(16)) float *C = ReadMatrix("E:\\Code\\conv\\C.bin");
__declspec(align(16)) float *K = ReadMatrix("E:\\Code\\conv\\K.bin");
__declspec(align(16)) float *R = new float[CSIZEX*CSIZEY];
```

The code crashes at y=1 so I feel there might be a mistake with the way I handle the pointers. The interesting thing is that if I replace the reinterpret_casts with _mm_set_ps, i.e.

```
__m128 KpSSE = _mm_set_ps(Kp[0], Kp[1], Kp[2], Kp[3]);
__m128 CpSSE = _mm_set_ps(Cp[0], Cp[1], Cp[2], Cp[3]);
__m128 DPtmp = _mm_dp_ps(KpSSE, CpSSE, 0xFF);
_mm_store_ss(&fDPtmp, DPtmp);
```

the whole thing works just fine although slower, which I blame on all the copy operations.

Can anybody please point me to what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Thank you very much

Pat

Update: Ok, so as pointed out by Paul the problem lies with ReadMatrix (or another solution would be to use _mm_loadu_ps). As for ReadMatrix(), it looks like this:

```
__declspec(align(16)) float* ReadMatrix(string path)
{
    streampos size;

    ifstream file(path, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        __declspec(align(16)) float *C = new float[size];
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&C[0]), size);
        file.close();

        return C;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

It does not do the trick. Is there any other way of doing this elegantly rather than being forced to read the file piece by piece and perform memcpy, which I assume should work?!

Update:

Still does not seem to want to work after

```
__declspec(align(16)) float* ReadMatrix(string path)
{
    streampos size;

    ifstream file(path, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        __declspec(align(16)) float *C = static_cast<__declspec(align(16)) float*>(_aligned_malloc(size * sizeof(*C), 16));
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&C[0]), size);
        file.close();

        return C;
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
}
```

I added the static_cast up there since it seemed necessary to get Paul's code to compile (i.e. _aligned_malloc returns a void pointer). I am getting close to just read chunks of the file with fread and memcpy them into an alligned array. :/ Yet again I am finding myself asking for advice. Thank you very much all.

Pat

PS: Non-SSE code works fine with these data structures. _mm_loadu_ps is slower than using the non-SSE code.

Comment: you cannot have a pointer on `__m128`. this doesn't make sense because   `__m128` map to any of the XMM[0-7] registers.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<__m128*>` is wrong, you should use `_mm_loadu_ps`.

Comment: @UmNyobe: no, the code is OK, and would work fine if the data were correctly aligned.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
__declspec(align(16)) float *C = ReadMatrix("E:\\Code\\conv\\C.bin");
```

All that the alignment directive achieves here is to align the pointer itself (i.e. `C`) to a 16 byte boundary, not the *contents* of the pointer.

You either need to fix `ReadMatrix` so that it returns suitably aligned data, or use `_mm_loadu_ps`, as others have already suggested.

Do not use `_mm_set_ps` as this will tend to generate a lot of instructions under the hood, unlike `_mm_loadu_ps`, which maps to a single instruction.

UPDATE

You have repeated the same mistake in ReadMatrix:

```
__declspec(align(16)) float *C = new float[size];
```

again this does not guarantee the alignment of the data, only of the pointer `C` itself. To fix this allocation you can use `_mm_malloc` or `_aligned_malloc`:

```
float *C = _mm_malloc(size * sizeof(*C), 16);
```

or

```
float *C = _aligned_malloc(size * sizeof(*C), 16);
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks a lot for your help. It does not quite work yet (see original post). If it is not too much of a burdon on you, could you (and the others of course), have another look?

Comment: Sure - see UPDATE in answer above.

Comment: Paul, it seems jinxed. Added the changes (please see update above) but it still does not work. Crashes on y=1 at `__m128 DPtmp = _mm_dp_ps(*KpSSE, *CpSSE, 0xFF);`, which is odd since debugging shows these two __mm128 are nicely filled. Could you, please, take another look?

Comment: It looks like CpSSE will be misaligned on the second iteration of y, because y = 1.

Comment: @PaulR, How can one handle data which isn't a multiplication of 8 / 16 and use SSE?

Comment: @Drazick: depending on the use case you would typically use unaligned loads, masking or a scalar loop to handle the unaligned/incomplete vector at the start/end of each row.

Comment: Where can one read about technique to handle it? For instance on arbitrary sized images? You mention masking.

Comment: @Drazick: there are some questions and answers that incidentally cover some aspects of this, but it might be a good idea to post a new question on this specific topic, as there are a number of different techniques for different use cases and it would be good to collect them all together in one place.

Comment: What should I search for to find those questions? Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick: use the `[simd]` or `[sse]` tags when searching and browse the answers, particularly those with source code. If you ask a new question though I'll answer it with some of the more common techniques, and no doubt others will join in too.

Answer (score 1):

In `ReadMatrix`, you have no guarantee whatsoever that the `new` expression returns a properly aligned pointer. It doesn't matter that you assign to an aligned pointer (and I'm not even sure if your syntax means the pointer itself is aligned, or what it points to).

You need to use `_mm_align`, or `_mm_malloc`, or some other aligned allocation facility.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use reinterpret_cast here, and I understand _mmloadu_ps is slow. But there is another way. Unroll your loop, read in aligned data, and shift and mask in the new value before you perform operations on it. This will be fast and correct. That is, you can do some like this in your inner loop:

```
__m128i x = _mm_load_ps(p);
__m128i y = _mm_load_ps(p + sizeof(float));
__m128i z;

// do your operation on x 1st time this iteration here

z = _mm_slli_si128(y, sizeof(float) * 3);
x = _mm_srli_si128(x, sizeof(float));
x = _mm_or_si128(x, z);

// do your operation on x 2nd time this iteration here

z = _mm_slli_si128(y, sizeof(float) * 2);
x = _mm_srli_si128(x, sizeof(float) * 2);
x = _mm_or_si128(x, z);

// do your operation on x 3rd time this iteration here

z = _mm_slli_si128(y, sizeof(float));
x = _mm_srli_si128(x, sizeof(float) * 3);
x = _mm_or_si128(x, z);

// do your operation on x 4th time this iteration here

x = y; // don’t need to read in x next iteration, only y

loopCounter += 4 * sizeof(float);
```